# Javascript popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what I'm trying to make is a map of `Germany` with markers.
and when clicked on a marker a `div` `(content)` will show with some things in it

is there a way to let `JavaScript` know which marker I clicked and it will open the corresponding content div, in total it will be about 200 markers so it must be a decently efficient code and my knowledge about `JavaScript` is not that great

**this is the code I have for now**

```
<div class="map">
  <img src="/images/map.jpg">
</div>

<div class="markers" style="top: 60%; left: 35%;">
  <div class="content" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="markers" style="top: 20%; left: 60%;">
  <div class="content" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Test2</h1>
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include Javascript code.

Comment: There is none yet

Comment: You can add an ID to each marker in the HTML and access them using their ID with JavaScript

Comment: Yes I thought about that too but then I'm in a problem with the efficiency of the code what I will do is create the same script for 200 markers but there has to be a better way, to use one script for all 200 markers right?

Comment: data-attributes .....

Comment: This doesn’t need _any_ ids or other additional attributes. You add an event handler to all of your marker elements (either individually, by looping over them, or one handler using _event delegation_), and `content` element can simply be selected based on that it is a child of the currently clicked marker …

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is using event delegation and listen to the click on the parent. You can than determine what was clicked and you can toggle a class to show the hidden element. Basic idea:

```js
document.querySelector(".map-wrapper").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  // find if a marker was clicked
  var marker = e.target.closest('.marker');
  console.log(marker)
  // was one clicked?
  if (marker) {
    // Hide any others that may be showing
    var active = document.querySelector('.marker.active');
    if(active && active!==marker) {
      active.classList.remove('active');
    }
    // toggle the info so it shows/hides
    marker.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.map-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.marker {
  position: relative;
}

.marker::after {
  content: '';
}

.marker .content {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.marker.active .content {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  background-color: #CCFF00;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div class="marker" style="left:100px; top: 100px;">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Test1</h1>
      <p>test1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marker" style="left:150px; top: 270px;">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Test2</h1>
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marker" style="left: 46px; top: 143px;">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Test3</h1>
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add any IDs or other means to identify the correct .content to show.

Add a click event listener to each marker and toggle a class on the element. The rest can be done with CSS.

```js
// Find all of the .markers elements
const markers = document.querySelectorAll('.markers');

// Loop through the .markers
markers.forEach((marker) => {
  // Add event listener to each .marker
  marker.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')) {
      // If the clicked element is active, deactivate it...
      e.currentTarget.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
      // ...otherwise, deactivate any other active .markers...
      removeClass(markers, 'active');

      // ...and activate the clicked .marker
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
    }

  })
});

// Helper function to remove a class from a collection of elements
function removeClass(els, className) {
  els.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.remove(className);
  });
}
```

```css
.markers {
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.markers .content {
  display: none;
}

.markers.active .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="markers" style="top: 60%; left: 35%;">
  <p>
    Marker 1
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="markers" style="top: 20%; left: 60%;">
  <p>
    Marker 2
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Test2</h1>
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```